# Visual Studio Installation Failure due to Team Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I've been trying to install Visual Studio Community 2015 on my desktop but I keep having issues.

First, it wants me to install Windows Update KB2999226 which doesn't really make sense because it's a Win7 update and I'm running Win8.1. I've tried manualy installing this update but it never works, saying I can only have one wusa.exe running at a time, but I don't have any wusa.exe running when I check the Task Manager.

So to skip this I just cancel wusa.exe in the Task Manager when I run the Visual Studio installer. The installer continues but after a bit it crashes completely, showing this:

[image]

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a windows 8.1 version of the update.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49071